# XML signature to validate/verify with .cer (public key) in Android

Tags: android, certificate, x509certificate, public-key, xml-signature

I need some help to validate my XML signature to .cer(public key).

Basically this process happened for the offline ekyc verification on government-issued id card.

regarding sample of xml and .cert file is available on the below link has **1. Offline ekyc sample data** section. also, they have provided some code for .net language.

And I have tried to applied the same on android but it gives always false validate. Can you please help me to how can I convert into android that sample code?

**Reference link:** https://www.uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/developer-section/915-developer-section/tutorial-section.html

I have applied below code in android

```
public boolean verifySampleData(String SignatureValue,InputStream publicKeyCertificate){
    X509Certificate cert = createCert(publicKeyCertificate);
    java.security.Signature signat;
    boolean ret=false;
    try {
        signat = java.security.Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signat.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());

        byte[] s= readSignature(SignatureValue);
        ret = signat.verify(s,0,s.length);
        return ret;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
public static X509Certificate createCert (InputStream certStream) {
    X509Certificate certret = null;
    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        certret = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(certStream);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return certret;
}

byte[] readSignature(String input) throws Exception {
    byte[] data = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
    return Base64.encode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get the solution?

Comment: Still did not get the solution.